# Facebook API getting summary of likes in `/links` without deprecated FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get the total likes count for posts by a specific user. I'm calling `/photos` `/links` and `/statuses`. When adding `?fields=likes.summary(true)` I'm getting back the total sum of likes in `/photos` and `/statuses`, but this doesn't work.

How can I get summary of likes (total count) for links posted by a specific user?

I am aware of the option to use FQL, but that is deprecated. (`fql?q=SELECT like_info, link_id,comment_info FROM link WHERE link_id IN()` )

Answer (score 1):

Use the `links` edge

```
 me/links?fields=link,likes.summary(true)
```

The `total_count` field is the value you want. Although from the documentation

> `total_count` represents the approximate number of nodes on the likes
>   edge. The actual number of results returned might be different
>   depending on privacy settings.

Sample data from my feed

```
{
      "link": "http://www.quora.com/permalink/cyGokoKWB", 
      "id": "XXXXXXXXX", 
      "created_time": "2015-04-26T02:08:48+0000", 
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "XXXXXXXXX", 
            "name": "XXXXXXXXX"
          }
        ], 
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "before": "MTAxNTQ2NTI3OTIxOTA0Mzg=", 
            "after": "MTAxNTQ2NTI3OTIxOTA0Mzg="
          }
        }, 
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 1
        }
      }
    }
```

**EDIT**

@CBroe in the comments has sound advice, for *just* like's count do a `limit(0)` so you don't unnecessarily fetch a lot of the likes data and just retrieve the count.

```
me/links?fields=link,likes.summary(true).limit(0)
```

Sample data

```
 {
      "link": "http://jdh.hamkins.org/transfinite-epistemic-logic-puzzle-challenge/", 
      "id": "XxXXXXXXXXX", 
      "created_time": "2015-04-19T04:00:18+0000", 
      "likes": {
        "data": [
        ], 
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 1
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: If _only_ the number is of interest, and not individual likes, then I would also add `.limit(0)` – that will still get you the `data` part of the structure, but it will always be empty. (Otherwise you might get multiple individual likes in there, up to the default limit.)

Comment: @Slartibartfast it gives me this error       (#12) links field is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",

Comment: try me/feed?fields=link,likes.summary(true).limit(0) in the 2.4+ API